# Azure Linux Container Web App does not resolve name within the vnet using private DNS

Tags: azure, docker, dns, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network

vnet is connected to my Web App through which I can communicate with other services and applications. When I specify the internal IP of another application to my application, everything works fine. But now the task has come from the management to remake it to use the internal DNS server and internal DNS names. In Azure vnet, in the DNS servers settings, I specified the IP of my DNS servers. I added 168.63.129.16 - now work. If you connect Windows VM to the network everything works fine. Perhaps something needs to be added to the Dockerfile or Linux Container Web App settings so that integration with vnet and DNS works.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If your web application is integrated with the virtual network, your application would be able to communicate with the applications in the virtual network

After integrating your web application with the virtual network, you need to perform sync network action

Go to Azure portal --> Go to your App Service plan where the web app is hosted --> Under Networking, select Virtual Network Integration --> select Sync Network

[image]

Once the sync action is complete, you would be able  to communicate with your internal application using the DNS name from your web application

**Reference**: [Name resolution for resources in Azure virtual networks | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances#web-apps)